# Symfony 6.3 client->loginUser does not work

Tags: symfony, testing, symfony6, php-pest

I have an issue that i don't understant. I m trying to make a fonctionnal test but i need to authenticate my user. I have this following code :

`it('test profileController page profile', function () {

```
self::ensureKernelShutdown();
$client = static::createClient();

$userRepository = static::getContainer()->get(UserRepository::class);
$urlGenerator = $client->getContainer()->get('router.default');

// retrieve the test user
$testUser = $userRepository->loadUserByIdentifier('User_Test1@test.com');

// simulate $testUser being logged in
$client->loginUser($testUser);

$client->request(
    Request::METHOD_GET, 
    $urlGenerator->generate('profile', ['_locale' => 'fr'])
);

$statusCode = $client->getResponse()->getStatusCode();
expect($statusCode)->toBe(200);
```

})->group('in_work');`

This code work but i m not authenticated so the controller redirect me to the home page and my test send me a failed asertion :

`Failed asserting that 302 is identical to 200.`

I want to create an authenticated user but i don't now why it does not work. I m using symfony 6.3 and pest for testing.

I had check $testUser, it not null and implement UserInterface. I had try to set roles in my user, try to use differents user, but in my controller, $this->getUser() always return null.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Why not inspect the response for more details? Why not use XDebug to step through the execution?

Comment: I ve try different authentication systeme, by sending data in client, try to connect by form ect... but the probleme is solved, i have multiple Authenticator and loginUser doesn't now wich one chose.
I never used Xdebug, i will try next time ^^

Answer (score 0):

I found the probleme, i use different Authenticator with 'custom_authenticator' in security.yaml,

add this in your firewall in security.yaml

`entry_point: App\Security\LoginAuthenticator \n http_basic: ~`

And loginUser will use the correct Authenticator !
Hope it will help people in the future